# C++ Text Array with User Input, then printing the input

Tags: c++, arrays

I’m hoping someone could help me out. Below is my current code. Please be gentle, this is legitimately my first program in C++, and it’s been about a year since I last touched C. And yes, this is for homework ~ I’ve used this page enough to know it’s asked quite a bit ;)

What I’m having an issue with, and struggling to find something moderately helpful regarding it, is how do I create an array to store user input text?

As you can see from the flow of the code: I ask how many items does the user want to purchase… this then dictates the looping, asking the user for the item name being purchased, the cost per item, and the total quantity. I am fine with the math part ~ I have the total items purchased and the running subtotal printing out pretty accurately. However, what I would like to do is print, in order, the names of the items that were purchased, too.

Current Code Output:

```
How many items do you want to enter? 3
What is the item name? Honey
What is the unit price for Honey? 5.99
How many purchased? 3
What is the item name? Milk
What is the unit price for Milk? 2.79
How many purchased? 2
What is the item name? chocolate
What is the unit price for chocolate? 1.97
How many purchased? 5

Bill Date: 
Items Purchased: 10
Subtotal: 33.4
```

In between “Bill Date” and “Items Purchased” I would like to list, line by line, the (3) items purchased: Honey, Milk, and chocolate. It’s the storing of the item name and incrementing it that I am very much stuck on. If someone could point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it. And please, the lengthier you explain the how's and why's, the better for me. Text/char arrays and I are mere acquaintances, whereas numerical int arrays and I are drinking buddies.

Thank you!! :D

---

Desired Code Output:

```
Bill Date: 
Honey
Milk
chocolate
Items Purchased: 10
Subtotal: 33.4
```

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int itemCount = 0, i, itemQty;
    int numOfItems = 0;
    char itemName[25];
    double itemCost;
    double itemSub;
    double subtotal = 0;

    cout << "How many items do you want to enter? ";
    cin >> itemCount;

for(i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
{
    cout << "What is the item name? ";
    cin >> itemName;
    cout << "What is the unit price for " << itemName << "? ";
    cin >> itemCost;
    cout << "How many purchased? ";
    cin >> itemQty;

    numOfItems = numOfItems + itemQty;
    itemSub = itemQty * itemCost;
    subtotal = subtotal + itemSub;
}

cout << "\n\tItems Purchased: " << numOfItems;
cout << "\n\tSubtotal: " << subtotal << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to make a struct with members `itemCost` `itemName` and `itemQty`. Make `itemName` a `std::string`. change array of items to `std::vector` of above structs and use std::sort to sort the vector before printing its elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the largest number of items to be purhcased?...I suppose it is 100..Instead of making an array of chars you can make an array of string so change the line `char itemName[25];` to `string itemName[100];` then inside the for loop change the input and output of itemname to `cin >> itemName[i];
    cout << "What is the unit price for " << itemName[i] << "? ";`
then you can output the names of items at last this way:

```
    for(int i=0;i<itemCount;i++)
    {
    cout<<endl<<itemName[i];
    }
cout << "\n\tItems Purchased: " << numOfItems;
            cout << "\n\tSubtotal: " << subtotal << "\n";
```